# How to embed ICC color profile in PDF other than Illustrator for Vector images

Tags: ghostscript, inkscape

[Illustrator prompt on Color profile information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EvA9.png)In Illustrator there is an option to embed ICC color profile to the PDF like wise is there any command line tools to embed ICC color profiles to the vector images. I have tried Ghostscript and Inkscape nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient information here to answer your question. What ICC profiles do you want to embed, and under what conditions do you want to embed them, ie for what purpose ?

(Note that 'image' in PDF means a bitmap image, so you can't have a 'vector' image)

Ghostscript will be starting with input (PostScript, PDF, XPS, PXL or PCL) which already describes the content in a particular colour space, depending on the input format this could be DeviceGray, DeviceRGB, DeviceCMYK, /Separation, /DeviceN, CIEBasedA, CIEBasedABC, CIEBasedDEF, CieBasedDEFG, ICCBased, Lab, CalGray or CalRGB.

If the input is ICCBased then Ghostscript will of course emit the ICC profile describing that space. If the input is anything else, then how is Ghostscript supposed to know what is the correct ICC profile to use ? You would have to know the characteristics od the (for example) CMYK space that the application which produced the input file was using.

If you know the characteristics of the colour and space that you are using then you can embed an OutputIntent profile (possibly this is what you mean but you haven't said so). To do that with Ghostscript you will need to construct a series of pdfmark operations. There is code in ghostpdl/lib/PDFA_def.ps that does exactly that, because a PDF/A file which is not in a device-independent colour space requires an OutputIntent profile.

Comment: ICC profiles were embedded depending upon the color space of the PDF. To every image the color profile need to be embedded. The purpose of embedding is to print the images with the embedded color profile.

Comment: Image in PDF can also be a vector. Try converting the EPS file to PDF and it wont get rasterized or Bitmapped.

Comment: No, an 'image' in a PDF file is a bitmap, not vectors. A PDF file may contain vector content, but in that case its not an image, its vectors. It seems you still don't really kow what you are asking for. You say that ICC profiles are 'embedded depending on the colour space of the PDF'. That's true only for an ICCBased colour space. As I indicated above there are many alternative possible colour spaces. If your input has been created without using ICCBased colour spaces there is no trivial way for an application (such as Ghostscript) to know what ICC profile to use in place of the defined space.

Comment: OutputIntent profile are these suggestions. Does that help me to embed the ICC color profile. I used to check this in Illustrator. If the color profile is embedded it shows the attached prompt while opening.